# Change view in region using Prism, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Attempting to create a view with a  region i wish to change at runtime.  But get error at runtime as below...

```
        public MainWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdatedEvent>().Subscribe(Updated);
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MapCenterChnagedEvent>().Subscribe(MapCenterChnagedEventHandler);

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<AssetSelectedEvent>().Subscribe(AssetSelectedEventHandler);
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(Views.GeoAssets));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegionAsset", typeof(Views.AssetDetails));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegionAsset", typeof(Views.Logs));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegionAsset", typeof(Views.Keys));

        object view = container.Resolve<Views.Logs>();
        object view2 = container.Resolve<Views.Keys>();


        IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions["ContentRegionAsset"]; //get error , _regionManager has no regions defined
        region.Activate(view); trying to make view logs the active view

    }
```

VIEW XAML

Comment: So where and how do you define your actual regions, i.e. how is the "ContentRegionAsset" defined and why didn't you include it in your sample?

Answer (score 0):

The view model does not look like a good place to register views. I'd rather navigate there, because the view model might get created multiple times and view registration is more of a one-time thing.

Side notes:

- injecting the container is evil -  inject a factory instead
- if you want to show an object, don't create a view in the view model - create a view model instead
- don't use the field in the constructor if you can use the parameter (because otherwise you won't get notified if you can remove the field during refactoring later on)

Comment: thanks :) Are you suggesting to register views in app.cs?

Comment: In Prism 7, yes, otherwise in the bootstrapper.